# shiny R hyperlink to table value

Tags: r, hyperlink, shiny

This is a similar question to what people asked before about Shiny package R  but I could not find specific directions on adding hyperlinks on a table which I obtained from biomart(below). I am sorry I am not in liberty to disclose all of the code and data. There are two tables tab separated in the user interface. I want GeneX in 'TAB separated table 1' to be hyperlinked to GeneX in TAB separated table 2. Please let me know if anything is not clear. Thanks in advance

################# TAB separated table 1

Species ESNTID      ESNTID              Gene

ENSxxxxxxxx         ENSxxxxxxxx         **GeneX**

################# TAB separated table 2

Ensembl.Gene.ID ## Associated.Gene.Name ## GO.Term.Accession    ## GO.Term.Definition   ## GO.domain

ENSXXXXXXXX  ## **GeneX**   ##                GO:xxx      ##           A membrane coat adaptor ... ## cellular_component

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, the two tables are one below the other and if the user clicks on GeneX in table1 it will scroll down to the row in table2? if that's it you could probably use html anchors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for not being clear.

In the web interface of the shiny, I want an interactive link on the gene names of TAB separated table 2. When I click on Gene X in the TAB separated table 2, I want TAB separated table 1 to show entries with Gene X only others disappear. Likewise, when I click on a Gene Y link on TAB separated table 2 (not shown but there are entries with Gene Y I assure you), in the web interface of TAB separated table 1 only entries with Gene Y should be shown.  

Hope this is clear and please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/73291/#73323  I also dared to ask the same question in bioconductor support page. You can have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are not talking about hyperlinks at all. You want to filter Table 1 based on row selections in Table 2.

I suggest using `renderDataTable` in the `DT` package to render your tables. You can then access the indices of your selected rows in Table 1 (e.g. `input$table1_rows_selected`) and use these to filter or create Table 2.